# Are PEX messages exchanged between 2 Seeds

Tags: bittorrent, torrent, peer-exchange

I have a fair knowledge of BitTorrent protocol. One questions has been bugging me for a while.

Always a seeding client immediately disconnects from another seed. Got a couple of questions there.

1. Is the disconnect made on the local side / remote side / both?
2. Before the disconnection takes place, are peers exchanged through PEX?

I think if seeds are able to exchange peer info to other seeds through PEX, it will help improve peer discovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification does not mandate if and when seeds may disconnect other seeds, although it [acknowledges the behavior](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0011.html#filling-underpopulated-lists) and allows seeds to include recently seen seeds in its PEX list which should allow downloaders to discover more seeds.
The exact timing of disconnects is largely up to implementations.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So my understanding is seeds can include recently seen seeds in its PEX list and exchange to connected peers. But my doubt is more towards whether a seed can exchange its connected peers to other seeds in the very short period they were connected to.

Comment: "But my doubt is more towards whether a seed can exchange" - well, that part is implementation-specific, it can't be answered generally. You'll have to test that against individual clients. But anyway, getting the information to peers is probably enough, as they will either have too many seeds to deal with anyway or will PEX among each other.